# What is this bucket sort implementation doing?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, bucket-sort

This is my code for bucket sort in Python.

```
from random import randrange


def insertion_sort(aList):
    for i in range(1, len(aList)):
        for j in range(i, 0, -1):
            if aList[j] < aList[j-1]:
                aList[j], aList[j-1] = aList[j-1], aList[j]
    return aList

def bucket_sort(aList):
    buckets =  [[]] * len(aList)
    for index, value in enumerate(aList):
        buckets_index = value * len(aList) // (max(aList) + 1)
        buckets[buckets_index].append(value)

answer = []

for bucket in buckets:
    answer.extend(insertion_sort(bucket))
    # answer += insertion_sort(bucket)

print(buckets[0])
print("\n")
# return answer


aList = [randrange(10) for _ in range(100)]
print(aList)
print("\n")
answer = bucket_sort(aList)
#print(answer)
```

What is happening? When I run the code, I always find that the first list in buckets is already sorted and the other lists in buckets are all copies of it.
Do I need the insertion sort for each list?
What would I use the "answer" variable for?!

I'm mainly relying on [this visualization](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/BucketSort.html).

Comment: question is not clear .. what is your requirement

Comment: Would be helpful for a non bucket user to see how you import it and what bucket actually is.

Comment: I think I know what your problem is, but it'd be nice if you could show some output, and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: @ymbirtt Isn't bucket sort just another sorting algorithm ?! .. My requirement is sorting a list !

Comment: I'm aware of that, but what I think the problem is and what you think the problem is could be completely disparate. If you show me exactly what happened and write out exactly what you expected to happen, then your problem becomes unambiguous.

Comment: I don't see buckets defined so your code would error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that i notice right off the bat is that you initialize your variable buckets as `buckets =  [[]] * len(aList)`. This makes a list of identical copies of the empty list. As such, any modification of this list is replicated in every element of `buckets`. Change this line to:

```
buckets =  [[] for _ in xrange(len(aList))]
```

To check if the lists inside the list are separate object, you could check their id's:

```
print [id(x) for x in buckets]
```

This should print a list of unique numbers.

Comment: It worked ^_^. However the number of empty is a too high. On a list of size of 10000 the number of empty buckets is 9000 consistently. Do you know why is that?

Comment: I don't know, but probably the number of buckets should not be the same as the number of values in your list... Also, fix your indentation in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this bucket sort would be more efficient and is more pythonesque.

```
def bucket(k):
    unique = list(set(k))
    values = [k.count(uni) for uni in unique]
    result = ([unique[uni] for i in range(values[uni])] for uni in range(len(unique)))
    result = sum(result, [])
    return result
```